# Apache HttpClient - Retry-After header

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-commons-httpclient

Any idea how apache http client handles Retry-After header ? 
Apache has given default retry handler implementation, but I am not able to see any retry header based logic there. 
if it does not handles the retry header, whats the proper way to implement it. (date parsing and sleep logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following link where we can see sample implementation for handling retry header

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHINDIG-1218?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel